# Difference between "Gtk+ theme" and "Current theme" entries in Gnome Tweak Tool

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, gtk3, gnome-tweak-tool

As you can see below, *Adwaita* is selected both as the *Gtk+ theme*, and the *Current theme*.

[image]

What is the difference? Also, some themes are available as "current" and others as Gtk+ ones.

Also, why do some themes change just some aspects, e.g. most that I install manually don't affect window borders.

What should I use to "fully" set a theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference? Also, some themes are available as "current" and others as Gtk+ ones.

To me this is a bug because, as it is it confuses the user. The menu labeled *GTK Theme* is the theme that is applied to change the overall look of the windows and the one labeled *Current Theme* is the theme of the window borders, I believe it was previously (and properly) called *Windows Theme*.

> Also, why do some themes change just some aspects, e.g. most that I install manually don't affect window borders.
>
> What should I use to "fully" set a theme?

*Most* themes include the GTK theme and a window border to go along with it, to change it you have to select it from Gnome Tweak Tool.

Comment: Bonus question: why is Adwaita the only theme that seems to apply to Firefox? Whenever I use some other theme, Firefox switches to that awful default Gtk+ look...

Comment: Have you selected the theme and then restarted firefox?

Comment: yes I have. It seems to be a problem with the theme itself. I have found some theme, called "MediterraneanNight", that does with Firefox. Anyway, thanks for explaining, accepted!

Answer (score 0):

current themes should be placed in dir /usr/share/themes  and affects window style

gtk3 themes can be placed in dir /usr/share/themes  or  ~/.themes it will not affect window style if placed there.